# how to get resolved alerts in email notification in prometheus alert manager

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

i had my prometheus setup and prometheus alert manager configured ,
when a alert is resolved how to get notification on resolved alerts
in email
at present only alerting the particular cpu , memory , hdd value is exceeding
but when the values comes to OK status , i need to get notification
in email , is that possible , any clues to resolve this issue

Answer (score 2):

open the file and add the parameter like below,

```
$ vim /path_to/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml
send_resolved: true
```

Now save and exit

```
$ sudo sytemctl restart alertmanager.service
```

This will do the job